# PostgreSQL will not connect

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am attempting to use PostgreSQL for the first time for a project. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio with Ubuntu terminal. I've been scouring the internet for upwards of 7 hours at this point, and I absolutely cannot figure out how to get this server running. It seems like it's refusing the connection with a "permission denied" error. I've tried a multitude of different suggestions from this site as well as a dozen other sites at this point. I'm at a loss.

```
config_file="/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf"  exited with status 1:

2020-08-23 00:41:40.319 EDT [6708] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-4) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-8ubuntu1) 9.3.0, 64-bit
2020-08-23 00:41:40.322 EDT [6708] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "127.0.0.1": Permission denied
2020-08-23 00:41:40.322 EDT [6708] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2020-08-23 00:41:40.322 EDT [6708] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
2020-08-23 00:41:40.322 EDT [6708] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
2020-08-23 00:41:40.323 EDT [6708] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server

I also get this error when trying to access my server through rails:

psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: Get the pid using `lsof -i tcp:5432` and then do `kill -9 <pid>`. The error is due to another process is listening on the 5432 port. So either, change the port in your code or kill the process with the method I suggested.

Comment: @shmsr On Ubuntu I would expect "Address already in Use", not "Permission denied", in that case.  (Despite the Hint).

Comment: @jjanes Yeah, that is also correct. Then maybe selinux or some firewall, iptables setting?

Comment: @shmsr Yeah, I would suspect selinux or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is because of ‘SELinux’. Make sure it’s in “permissive” mode.

```
setenforce 0

# getenforce
Permissive
```

More information about config: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-disable-or-set-selinux-to-permissive-mode/